# choose jdk used for android development in netbeans

Tags: android, netbeans

Any way to choose which jdk Netbeans 7.1 choose to build / sign an Android project.

Due to some issue between Android and JDK7 (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=830), I had no choice but to start Netbeans with --jdk-home to specify some jdk 6. It seems it picks the default jdk for running Ant.

I'd like to be able to have JDK 7 for all my projects but my Android app.

Answer (score 0):

right click `Project--->Properties--->Libraries---> Right side "Java Platform"-->Select the version you want`. If version you are looking for is not there, you can add by going through Manage Platforms.

Comment: That's how you do it in a java project, this one is an android project. There is no "java platform" there. "Manage Platforms" let me manage them, but I couldn't find a way to associate a java platform with an android project.